# React Native Get Async Storage return Unhandled Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Right now I want to save user token after the user login successful.

Here is my code:

```
onPress(){
  return axios.post('https://api.example.net/v1/user/auth/login', {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }).then((response) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.login._cxz, () => {
      console.log('success');
    });
    this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{name: 'tweets'}]);
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({errorMessage: error.response.data.message});
  });
}
```

I already make sure that `response.data.login._cxz` has a value.
Right until here is working. the login will redirect me to `tweets` route.

On my tweets.js:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state({token : ''});
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token', (err, value) => {

      console.log(value);
    })
  }
```

I just simple `console.log` it to view if the token is saved or not.
But everytime login is done (the success log is appear). I always got this error when enter my tweets:

[image: error]

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that the `then` callback is throwing an error at `navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack`:

```
.then((response) => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.login._cxz, () => {
    console.log('success');
  });
  this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{name: 'tweets'}]);
})
.catch((error) => {
  this.setState({errorMessage: error.response.data.message});
});
```

The error is then caught in the `catch` block, but because the error is a normal JavaScript `Error` and not an axios error, it does not have `response` property, and therefore trying to access `error.response.data` causes the undefined error.

The easy way to detect the kind of error is to duck-type it: If the error has a `response`, then it's an axios error, otherwise another error:

```
.catch((error) => {
  if (error.response && error.response.data) {
    this.setState({errorMessage: error.response.data.message});
  } else {
    this.setState({errorMessage: error.message});
  }
});
```

The error caused by `immediatelyResetRouteStack` is probably coming from the React render pass that is synchronously executed on the same call stack. Once you fix the broken `.catch` you'll see what the error message is, but a good guess for a culprit in your limited code sample is:

```
this.state({token : ''});
```

Which should be an property assignment, instead of a method call:

```
this.state = {token : ''};
```

Comment: well that all make sense. I try remove my `catch` and its all working properly but after I fix `this.state = {token: ''}`. Thanks!